# Angular Material Dialog Component Scrolling Issue at Startup

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

I am using Angular Material Dialog component within my app and within this dialog, I am presenting the a user a HTML table of data, that may have a scrollbar.

My issue is though, when I click the button to open the actual dialog, I noticed that the contents are immediately scrolled to the bottom, which is a nuisance, since I need to manually scroll back to the top.

I am using the standard setup as described here:

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

My dialog call is as follows:

```
myDialog(a: string, b: string) {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
            height: '500px',
            width: '800px',
            data: { a,b }
        });
}
```

What can I do to avoid this scroll to the bottom issue? I have tried some CSS such as `top: 0; position: fixed;` but to no avail.

Comment: this issue does not seem to relate with your dialog, it is with your component you using. can you show `MyDialogComponent`'s `HTML & CSS`

Comment: @WasiF interesteing. is there anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: may be your component's css or styles' css effecting. Please show your code

Comment: may be you set `scrollTop` property somewhere in your html or css. Provide [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com)

Comment: No scrollTop and completely removed my component CSS. Still have the same issue.

Comment: then you have to provide [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: Have just discovered that when I removed the close button within the mat-dialog-actions tags, all works fine. From what I can see, perhaps on load, it focuses on the Close button. How can I alter this or perhaps move the close button to the top?

Comment: can you show your code, so that I can resolve this ... I wanna know how you putting that close button. Have you just put any symbol like `X` or did something else in action-tag

Comment: Pls see my answer.

Comment: Hi Tony. I am a volunteer editor here, and one of the things we do is to edit questions so they are readable and useful for future readers. Your questions are rather chatty, and it would help us enormously if you could cut it down a bit. We discourage thanks/appreciation and so forth in posts themselves - thanks is expressed in votes and acceptances, and occasionally in comments (303 of your posts to repair). There's no need to say that "help would be great", as that's another 116 posts to repair. There's no need to "hope someone can help", that's another 81 posts.

Comment: I also count 36 items of txtspk from you ("pls" meaning "please") and 22 signatures. You're not on the top of the needs-edit leaderboard, but probably not far off.

Comment: I sometimes post this advice, which gives a good flavour of the succinctness that is widely preferred here: _Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by moving the following HTML code to the top of the page.

```
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <br>
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" mat-dialog-close (click)="closeDialog()" class="my-btn">
        Close
    </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me. The Dialog scrolled down automatically when opened. I realized that the dialog scrolled down to the first anchor tag it finds. This is really wierd. I solved it by adding a dummy anchor tag as the first child inside the dialog. <a href=""></a>

Comment: @Gagan: your comment helped me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

The reason it happans to you is that, the dialog component auto-focuses on the first input / button in your HTML content.
You should add 'autoFocus: false' to the Dialog options to prevent it.

```
myDialog(a: string, b: string) {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
        height: '500px',
        width: '800px',
        autoFocus: false,
        data: { a,b }
    });
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me 